# Cancel/Stop a currently ongoing scheduled cron event?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

If I scheduled a CPU-intensive job via a cron scheduled event, how do I go about stopping it or cancelling the job while it is currently running?

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or would you like to be able to cancel a cron event from somewhere on a regular basis, perhaps from another PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

Removing / un-scheduling obsolete cron jobs can be achieved using this code snippet.

```
add_action("init", "remove_cron_job"); 
function remove_cron_job() {
 wp_clear_scheduled_hook("my_schedule_hook"); 
}
```

Change the my_schedule_hook to cron’s hook name and add the code in your theme’s function.php file.

Comment: but this won't stop the job that's currently running.

Comment: Also wondering if this is possible (stopping the currently running cron)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete scheduled cron jobs via a SSH command line.
First, take a look at all your active and scheduled cron jobs by doing this command:

```
$ wp cron event list
```

Then you can delete any of the cron jobs by using their hook name. Let's say you have six jobs whose hook name is "crontrol_cron_job". You would run this command:

```
$ wp cron event delete crontrol_cron_job
```

You'll get a result of something like:

```
Deleted 6 instances of the cron event 'crontrol_cron_job'.
```